# Mathematica and Maple gives different values of a trigonometric definitite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Does anyone know how to solve this definite integral?

$$-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{i c \sin^2 x}{\pi^2(c^2 \cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)^2}dx}$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Mathematica gives the answer $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ while maple gives the answer  $-\frac{1}{4\pi}$. The integral arises from physics and neither mathematica nor maple allows me to see the detailed steps. I expect the answer to be $-\frac{1}{4\pi}$. However, when I try integration in complex plane using substitution $t=i c\cot x$ i get answer $-\frac{1}{2\pi}$ which is two times the expected value. When I use substitution $t=i c \cot x$ I obtain the folowing integral:

$$-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{i c \sin^2 x}{\pi^2(c^2 \cos^2 x-sin^2 x)^2}dx}=\int_{i 0}^{i \infty}{\frac{dt}{\pi^2(t^2+1)^2}}$$

Integrating this in complex plane over the contour that is one quarter of disc gives me $-\frac{1}{2\pi}$. Can someone please help me with this integral?

Comment: In which sense should this integral be computed? The integrand has a pole of order 2, so it cannot be integrated in ordinary sense.

Comment: What do you mean in which sense the integral should be computed?

Comment: Your antiderivative is divergent at the boundaries.  Maybe you can use Cauchy principal values?

Comment: The issue about where Mathematica vs Maple put branch cuts has come up on Mathematica.stackexchange before so try there.

Comment: This integral diverges to $+\infty$ either in improper-Riemann-integral sense or in Lebesgue-integral sense. If you want to give a meaningful value to this other than $+\infty$, you need to specify the notion of integral yo want to work with.

Comment: the integrands tends to infinity whenever $\tan x=c$ which is near the boundary of integral but not exactly at the boundary. Only when $c\rightarrow\infty$ it tends to go to infinity at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Forgot to mention that $c$ is real number, sorry

Comment: You still have singularities in the integral, it still diverges in the Riemann sense.  You get logarithms, what are the branch cuts you (or Maple or Mathematica) are using?

Comment: For $c=1$ Maple says the integral diverges, and even the CauchyPrincipalValue diverges.

Comment: Here is the thing, when i make substitution $t=i \frac{1}{c}\tan x$, $dt=i \frac{1}{c}\sec^2 x dx$ the following integral is obtained:

$$I = \int_{a}^{b}{\frac{t^2dt}{\pi^2(1+t^2)^2}}$$

If $\tan(x)$ is defined as:

$$tan(x)=i\frac{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}{e^{-i x}+e^{i x}}$$

then $tan(0)=i\frac{2}{2}=0 i$. On the other hand we have $tan(\frac{\pi}{2})=i \infty$, In thate case integral I becomes:

$$I = \int_{0 }^{\infty }{\frac{t^2dt}{\pi^2(1+t^2)^2}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{t^2dt}{\pi^2(1+t^2)^2}}=-\frac{1}{4\pi}$$

Comment: On the other hand if $tan(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}$ the limits are complex and the integral diverges.